# Computer crashes

Tags: cpu, crash, overclocking

I just installed a new motherboard, cpu, ram, and a psu. I am having problems because my computer will randomly crash(restart) and I can't seem to associate it with any specific thing that I'm doing or the computer is doing. I noticed that when I first put it together I couldn't run an os or anything until I increased my ram voltage to 1.8v. I don't know if I should increase the voltage, or maybe adjust the timing(I don't know hardly anything about that). I also notice that my mouse that I just purchased seems to randomly not be recognized by the system.

I also tried disabling my onboard audio, and that didn't help.

ALso, I've updated my mobo bios to the latest firmware, and updated windows 7 all the way.

Here's my specs

OS: Windows 7 64x

cpu-z 
http://valid.canardpc.com/show_oc.php?id=1334765

ram: W2000UA1GP

**Update**

Alright well, I backed off the multiplier to slow the cpu to 2.8ghz but I'm still experience the same problems, and the same cpu temps...I hover around 40c for the mobo and the processor

Comment: don't modify things, like I said, restore to defaults.

Comment: The defaults are what overclocked the cpu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically on default auto settings the board would overclock the cpu, so I had to set everything manually and it works fine.

Comment: Well that’s not right; it should be able to set things correctly. See if the motherboard has an updated (read fixed) BIOS available. Alternately, what may have been happening is that the motherboard (you didn’t specify which) has some sort of “turbo” feature (on mine it’s called *AI Overclock* and has a *Turbo* option for performance-mode) that overclocks the system automatically when possible (all the settings would still be set to auto). Look for that and turn it off; then the other settings being set to auto should run at the proper (and stable) speed.

Comment: All of that was shut off, and the bios was updated.

Answer (score 4):

You can't associate it with anything specific? I can. That machine is overclocked and probably has insufficient cooling. Some motherboards have a feature that will automatically power off the machine if it reaches a certain temperature, I believe Intel calls them "thermal events", not sure if AMD uses different terminology. You can adjust thermal alarm settings in the BIOS as well but I'd suggest assessing the issue properly rather than bypassing it to avoid trashing your hardware.

The stock for that chip is 2.8Ghz. You are running it at over 3.5Ghz. Put it back to stock and you will notice a much more stable system. Your CPU will thank you (and probably last longer). The easiest way to achieve this is to go into the BIOS and return it to setup defaults (usually one of the function keys will do this). I wouldn't recommend overclocking unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: That would do! HAHA

Comment: +1: If you are playing with the BIOS voltage settings just to get it running and you don't know why: Set it to defaults, close the lid, and step away. :)

Comment: oh damn. I wasn't intentionally overclocking the cpu, it was all set to auto, and yes, I don't have proper cooling to overclock at all. I can't believe I didn't notice that(Probubly because I planed on getting a 3.8 ghz processer, but settled for this one instead).

Comment: And also, all the defaults wouldn't let the computer operate. I read that DDr3 in dual-channel mode is supposed to run at 1.8v as opposed to the default 1.5...and that did fix a majority of my problems in the first place.

Comment: @Kelly, yes but only modify what's necessary. Make sure you aren't modifying the CPU's vcore and multiplier.